# How to remove elements with jQuery but still keep the space it exists in

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to hide or reveal an element with jQuery but still keep the space that it takes up on the page?
For example, a set of links with a paragraph underneath each. When the user hovers over the link the paragraph will disappear/appear but without the layout changing as the paragraph is removed.

Comment: You have to replace it with a spaceholder, which has the same dimensions

Comment: You could change the opacity of the element you want to hide

Comment: Building on the answers, you can `animate()` the `opacity` style property if you want a fade effect. But do not use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` in your case, because these methods will also "fully" show or hide the element, going against your prerequisite.

Answer (score 4):

The very simple way of doing this is with the `visiblity` CSS property:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function() {
    $(this).next().css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

The `$(this).next()` might need modification to find the correct element to show or hide.

Comment: Couldn't we do this with just CSS? `~`?

Comment: @j08691 Probably with `+`, yes, though it's likely the DOM structure isn't this simple.

Comment: Ah yup, `+`. Haven't had my coffee yet ;)

Comment: Thanks, I used a variation of this but added **visibility:hidden** to make the **'p'** invisible at the start.   http://jsfiddle.net/nellyb/ua22e/11/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just CSS, no JavaScript needed.

```
p {
    visibility:hidden;
}
a:hover + p {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GkMUn/)**

Comment: Was about to add this to my answer, but I'll give you a +1 instead.

Comment: thanks, this works, but can I control the speed that the element appears at? I thought I would have to use jQuery for this.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention speed or any kind of fade effect in your question, so as it stands no. However you could use CSS3 transitions and the element's opacity to do it without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with css:

```
jQuery('p').css('opacity', 0);
```

This way the element is invisible but still fills the space that it needs based on its dimensions. This way you can also animate it when you want to smoothly hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

> The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would have
>   been

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the element using build in jquery method:

$('#ElementId').hide();

and show it using:

$('#ElementId').show();

Comment: No, this sets `display` to `none`, so the elements occupy no space.